Hearing aid output
I am a bit confused:
I have designed a digital hearing aid system includes a mic, filter, delta modulator and an amplifier. I tested the system input and output and everything worked very well.
My input signal is too weak and it gets amplified and processed to a certain output level that doesn't pass 1V.
If the hearing aid frequency response is the plot of sound in dB (more than 40 dB) versus frequency, how can I plot my hearing aid frequency response if the output voltage does not pass 1 V?
To reach the level of 40 dB in sound this needs a very high voltages more than 500 V if I directly convert the output voltage to decibel!
Or do we treat the output sound of the hearing aid versus frequency as a gain in dB ?
note:  "that I'm working on MATLAB- Simulink and i get the output as a signal with amplitude"

It sounds like your model output the the output voltage of the amplifier. To get on actual sound pressure signal in Pascal, you need to add more stuff: a transducer, the acoustic loading the transducer (ear canal, ear drum, etc), leak path between transducer and microphone and to the outside air, etc.

Something is generally wrong. -40 dB of 500V is simply 5 V, and no microphone will give you 5 V output swing! More like 5 mV or 50 mV. Also, it's not clear why voltages play a role here at all – the input/out behaviour of a hearing aid (and hence, its frequency response) would be measured in input sound pressure vs output sound pressure, not in voltages; the voltages are, so to speak, just implementation details. Did you perhaps simply assume some much-to-large conversion factor from sound pressure to amplitude for the microphone? I think it becomes clear here that

you should really show us your whole model if you want us to be able to infer what's wrong with it.

1.-
To solve
how can I plot my hearing aid frequency response if the output voltage does not pass 1 V?
generate an input tone, single frequency, start at let's say f1=30   Hz
record input power P1 [W]
record output power P2 [W]
the gain of your device at f1 is P2/P1
Repeat with input frequency steps of 1 or 5 or 10 Hz
Keep recording P2/P1 at each frequency, up to let's say 20kHz
The frequency response of your device is P2/P1 over the range [f1:f2]
where you may have chosen f1=30 and f2=20000
2.-
In the comment
To reach the level of 40 dB in sound this needs a very high voltages more than 500 V if I directly convert the output voltage to decibel!
That 500V is 500% wrong. Please check again and let readers know.
3.-
and to
Or do we treat the output sound of the hearing aid versus frequency as a gain in dB ?
NO .
Gain has no units.
Gain is always in dB[ ] NO UNITS.
Voltage signals [V] are also dBV or dBmV or dBuV and the same signal, on a particular impedance has dBW or dBmW or dBuW .
Same signal measured over different impedance is going to show apparent different values.
Voltage signals can be translated to Power over a particular IMPEDANCE.
What impedance are you using?
Are you using same input impedance to output impedance?
